# Incorrect SQL generation on query

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

```
Dim records = From record In db.table
              Where record.Level = "Level 1"
              Where record.NewNumber IsNot Nothing
              Select record.Number
```

When I call records.ToString() I get an output like so:

> SELECT 
>       [Extent1].[Number] AS [Number]
>       FROM [dbo].[table] AS [Extent1]
>       WHERE [Extent1].[Level] = @p__linq__0

The where clause for NewNumber is not null is missing. If I change the linq to where NewNumber is nothing I get the following:

> SELECT 
>       CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C1]
>       FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
>       WHERE 1 = 0

What is going on here? The number field is my primary key and newnumber is just another field. I've only changed some of the names/values for this post. Executing both where clauses on the same line with And/AndAlso makes no difference.

The field NewNumber is configured as such.

> [Property](Function(x) x.NewNumber).HasMaxLength(20).HasColumnName("Newnumber").IsOptional()

Comment: AndAlso instead of the second Where ?

Comment: No difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF knows that `NewNumber` can't be `null`/`nothing` and either ignores the predicate (`IsNot Nothing`) because it's always true, or when it's always false (`Is Nothing`) it turns it into something that's easier to evaluate for the query optimizer.

Comment: Newnumber is a nullable nvarchar(20) so it shouldn't be optimizing like this.

Comment: Well, EF doesn't know it's nullable. It's probably mapped as required.

Comment: I thought the same right after I posted that and explicitly marked it as optional with no change to the SQL. Tho it says in the description that string properties are nullable by default.

Comment: I'm using an EntityTypeConfiguration class. [Property](Function(x) x.NewNumber).HasMaxLength(20).HasColumnName("Newnumber").IsOptional()

Comment: That's weird. There must be *something* that makes EF believe it's required. By the way, please add this part to your question.

Comment: Just to exclude the odd case: you do add the configuration class to the modelBuilder, do you?

Comment: Definitely the field is required from EF point of view. OP has to find why. Since `string` is optional by default, either data type is different, or the field is FK for required relationship etc.

Comment: I am adding it to the modelbuilder.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, that was exactly it. I had it set as a FK in a required relationship that should have been optional.